# shortcuts to program do not work win 10 home

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu

When I press the start key at the bottom left corner and press the first letter of the program the suggestion does not pop up anymore
FOr example before if I wanted to run livezilla program I would press the win key and then L and select livezilla
now it stopped working for some reason

Comment: From an admin command prompt run (1) DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /restore health and then (2) SFC /SCANNOW . Restart when done and test

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try:-

1. Delete the Temp files and Prefetch files from your windows.
2. Update your Windows to version 2004.
3. Reset your windows search.
4. Reset your PC.

How to delete the temp and prefetch files:-

**Make sure you are logged in as an administrator.**

1. Press "Windows key" + "R".
2. A small box will open in the bottom. Type "%temp%" and click on "OK".
3. Click on continue if it asks for permissions.
4. Press "ctrl" + "A" and then "shift" + "delete" to delete all the temporary files.
5. Close the window.
6. Again Press "Windows key" + "R".
7. A small box will open in the bottom. This time type "temp" and click on "OK".
8. Click on continue if it asks for permissions.
9. Press "ctrl" + "A" and then "shift" + "delete" to delete all the temporary files.
10. Close the window.
11. Again Press "Windows key" + "R".
12. A small box will open in the bottom. Type "prefetch" and click on "OK".
13. Click on continue if it asks for permissions.
14. Press "ctrl" + "A" and then "shift" + "delete" to delete all the Prefetch files.
15. Close the window.

Don't worry. Deleting these files won't cause any harm to your system.

**After this restart your PC. Do not Shut Down and Power On.**

If the above doesn't work:-

Use the Windows Search and Indexing troubleshooter to try to fix any problems that may arise. To do this, follow these steps:

**Select Start, then select Settings.**
In Windows Settings, select **Update & Security  > Troubleshoot** . Under Find and fix other problems, select Search and Indexing .
Run the troubleshooter, and select any problems that apply. Windows will try to detect and solve them.

You can also use a command prompt to open the troubleshooter. To do this, press **Windows logo key +R**, **enter cmd in the Open box, and then select OK**. At the command prompt, run the following command:

**msdt.exe -ep WindowsHelp id SearchDiagnostic**

If these two don't work try resetting search:-

**If you have Windows 10 1809 or older:-**

If the Windows 10 October 2018 Update or an earlier update is installed, reset Cortana to reset Windows Search. To do this, follow these steps:

Select Start , right-click Cortana, select More, and then select App settings.
In the Cortana settings, select Reset.

**If you have Windows 10 1903 or later:-**

Download the "ResetWindowsSearchBox.ps1" script from the Microsoft Download Center, and save the file to a local folder:
[Reset Windows Search PowerShell script](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/100295)

Right-click the file that you saved, and select Run with PowerShell.

If you are asked "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?," select Yes.

The PowerShell script resets the Windows Search feature. When the word "Done" appears, close the PowerShell window.

If you receive a "Cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system" error message, enter the following command on the command line of the PowerShell window, and then press Enter:

**Get-ExecutionPolicy**

Note The current policy appears in the window. For example, you might see Restricted. We recommend that you note this value because you'll have to use it later.

Enter the following command on the command line of the PowerShell window, and then press Enter:

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

Note You'll receive a warning message that explains the security risks of an execution policy change. Press Y, and then press Enter to accept the change.

To learn more about PowerShell execution policies, see About Execution Policies.
After the policy change is completed, close the window, and then repeat steps 2–4. However, when the "Done" message appears this time, DON'T close the PowerShell window. Instead, press any key to continue.

Revert to your previous PowerShell execution policy setting. To do this, enter the following command on the command line of the PowerShell window, press the Spacebar, enter the policy value that you noted in step 5, and then press Enter:

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy**

For example, if the policy that you noted in step 5 was Restricted, the command would resemble the following:

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Restricted**

Note You'll receive a warning message that explains the security risks of an execution policy change. Press Y, and then press Enter to accept the change and revert to your previous policy setting.

Close the PowerShell window.

The above steps should be enough to fix any windows search problems. But if your problem is not fixed using above methods try Resetting your PC or upgrading to version 2004.

Hope this helps!